# Why are instance being already created being deleted and recreated?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have created the resources with Terraform 0.12.6.  However, without making any changes to the code and doing "terraform apply" the process wants to destroy the existing EC2 and rebuild them.  I would like to know why it is doing so and what is incorrect below.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web_ui" {
  count                       = 2
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ami.id
  instance_type               = var.type_m5lg
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  key_name                    = var.key_name
  security_groups             = [var.vpc_security_group_ids, var.sg_devops, var.sg_common]
  subnet_id                   = (data.aws_subnet.subnetid)[count.index].id
  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
  ebs_block_device {
    device_name           = "/dev/sdb"
    volume_size           = "200"
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
  tags = "${merge(
    local.common_tags,
    map(
      "Name", "${var.name}-${var.prog}-${var.env}${count.index + 1}-${var.ec2_name_web}-use1.xyz.com"
    )
  )}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the
**security_groups** = [var.vpc_security_group_ids, var.sg_devops, var.sg_common]
**TO**
**vpc_security_group_ids** = [var.vpc_security_group_ids, var.sg_devops, var.sg_common]
fixed the issue.

Based on the comment from @stack72 hashicorp/terraform#7853